Problema de hidratacion de mi pagina [profile]
Tengo un problema de hidratacion de mi pagina [profile] que carga los datos del perfil de un usuario, puede ser el perfil propio o ajeno. Estoy intentando renderizar los botones editar perfil y seguir/dejar de seguirdependiendo si es su propio perfil o el perfil de otra persona respectivamente.
Estoy intentando renderizar lo siguiente:
{ user.id === profile._id  
   ? <ProfileEditForm profile={profile} onUpdateProfile={handleUpdateProfile} /> 
   : ( isFollowing 
       ? < Button onClick={() => handleUnfollow()} > Dejar de seguir </Button>
       : < Button onClick={() => handleFollow(id, user.id)} > Seguir </Button>
     )
}

Sobre el problema
En el codigo tengo la logica que:

Si el user.id(id del usuario actual) es igual a profile._id(id del perfil que esta visistando) significa que es su propio perfil y debe aparecer el boton editar perfil.
En caso contrario, debe aparecer el boton seguir/dejar de seguir dependiendo si lo sigue o no.

El codigo completo es:
/* <----------------------- FUNCIONES ---------------------------> */
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

/* <---------------- COMPONENTES MATERIAL UI --------------------> */
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

/* <----------------------- ICONOS UI ---------------------------> */
import CachedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Cached';
import ViewHeadlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ViewHeadline';
import BookmarkIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Bookmark';
import WorkspacePremiumIcon from '@mui/icons-material/WorkspacePremium';

/* <--------------------- COMPONENTES NAV ----------------------> */
import NavBar from "@/components/nav/NavBar";

/* <------------------- COMPONENTES FORM ---------------------> */
import ProfileEditForm from '@/components/form/ProfileEditForm';

/* <------------------- COMPONENTES VIEWER ---------------------> */
import PostProfileViewer from "@/components/viewer/PostProfileViewer";
import BadgesProfileViewer from '@/components/viewer/BadgesProfileViewer';

/* <------------------------ CONTEXTO --------------------------> */
import { useAuth } from "@/context/AuthContext";

/* <----------------------- SERVICIOS  -------------------------> */
import { getUserInformation, getUserFollowedHashtags, updateUser, followUser } from "@/services/user.service";


const Profile = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  // Desectructuracion datos de usuario (user.id).
  const { user } = useAuth();
  // Desesctructuracion de perfil de usuario y asignacion a variable `id`.
  const { profile: id } = router.query;
  // Seteo de datos del perfil de usuario.
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
  // Seteo de datos de hashtags.
  const [hashtags, setHashtags] = useState([]);
  // Seteo de secciones del perfil seleccionada, `0` por default.
  const [section, setSection] = useState(0);

  const [isFollowing, setIsFollowing] = useState(false);

  //<----------------------------------- DATOS DE USUARIO ----------------------------------->
  const fetchProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await getUserInformation(id);
      const data = response.data.data;
      console.log(data);
      setProfile(data);
      setIsFollowing(data.followers.includes(user.id));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("FRONTEND: Error en Profile -> fetchProfile() -> id:", id, error);
    }
  };
  // Estadistica de total de seguidos de usuario, incluye la suma de tanto como usuarios y hashtags
  const totalSeguidos = (profile.followed ? profile.followed.length : 0) + (hashtags.length);

  //<---------------------------------- HASHTAGS DE USUARIO --------------------------------->
  const fetchHashtags = async (ids) => {
    try {
      const response = await getUserFollowedHashtags(ids);
      const data = response.data.data;
      setHashtags(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("FRONTEND: Error en Profile -> fetchHashtags()", error);
    }
  };

  //<---------------------------------- MANEJO DE CARGA DE DATOS  --------------------------------->
  // Encargado de ejecutar solicitudes para cargar los datos cada 
  // vez que cambie la id tanto como del usuario y del perfil.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      fetchProfile();
      fetchHashtags(user.id);
    }
  }, [id, user.id]);

  const handleUpdateProfile = (updatedProfile) => {
    setProfile((prevProfile) => ({
      ...prevProfile,
      ...updatedProfile,
    }));
  };

  const handleFollow = async (userFollower, userFollowed) => {
    try {
      await followUser(userFollowed, userFollower)
      setIsFollowing(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("FRONTEND: Error en Profile -> handleFollow()", error);
    }
  };



  return (
    <>
      <NavBar userId={user.id} />

      <section className="relative block h-[500px]">
        <div className="absolute top-0 w-full h-full bg-center bg-cover" style={{ backgroundImage: "url('https://img.myloview.fr/images/black-and-white-pattern-on-white-background-abstract-design-700-176625414.jpg')"}}>
          <span id="blackOverlay" className="w-full h-full absolute opacity-50 bg-black"></span>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className="relative py-16 ">
        <div className="container mx-auto px-4">
            <div className="relative flex flex-col min-w-0 break-words bg-white w-full mb-6 shadow-xl rounded-lg -mt-64 ">
                  {/*<-------------------------------------------------------- CABECERA DE PERFIL -------------------------------------------------------->*/}
                  <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
                        {/*<---------------- SECCION-CABECERA FOTO DE PERFIL------------------>*/}
                        <div className="w-full lg:w-3/12 px-4 lg:order-2 flex justify-center items-center">
                          <div className="absolute -top-32 overflow-hidden h-56 w-56 flex justify-center items-center rounded-full shadow-lg shadow-zinc-600 select-none">
                            <Avatar src={`http://localhost:3001/uploads/profiles/${profile.profilePicture}`} sx={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}></Avatar>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        {/*<------------------ SECCION-CABECERA INSIGNIAS -------------------->*/}
                        <div className="w-full lg:w-4/12 px-4 lg:order-3">
                          <div className="py-6 px-3 mt-32 sm:mt-0 mx-auto flex justify-center">
                              { user.id === profile._id  
                                  ? <ProfileEditForm profile={profile} onUpdateProfile={handleUpdateProfile} /> 
                                  : (
                                    isFollowing 
                                    ? <Button onClick={() => handleUnfollow() } className='bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-400 text-white normal-case py-2 px-4'>Dejar de seguir</Button>
                                    : <Button onClick={() => handleFollow(id, user.id)} className='bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-400 text-white normal-case py-2 px-4'>Seguir</Button>
                                  )
                              }
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        {/*<------------------ SECCION-CABECERA ESTADISTICAS ------------------>*/}
                        <div className="w-full lg:w-4/12 px-4 lg:order-1 flex justify-center items-center">
                            <div className="flex justify-center py-2 px-2 lg:pt-4 my-1">
                              <div className="lg:mr-4 p-3 text-center hover:bg-zinc-200 rounded transition ease-linear select-none">
                                <span className="text-xl font-bold block uppercase tracking-wide text-blueGray-600">{profile.posts ? profile.posts.length : 0}</span>
                                <span className="text-sm text-blueGray-400">Publicaciones</span>
                              </div>

                              <div className="lg:mr-4 p-3 text-center hover:bg-zinc-200 rounded transition ease-linear select-none">
                                <span className="text-xl font-bold block uppercase tracking-wide text-blueGray-600">{totalSeguidos}</span>
                                <span className="text-sm text-blueGray-400">Seguidos</span>
                              </div>
                              
                              <div className="lg:mr-4 p-3 text-center hover:bg-zinc-200 rounded transition ease-linear select-none">
                                <span className="text-xl font-bold block uppercase tracking-wide text-blueGray-600">{profile.followers ? profile.followers.length : 0}</span>
                                <span className="text-sm text-blueGray-400">Seguidores</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>

            </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Profile;


¿A que te refieres con “hidratación”? La condicional ternaria parece estar bien, y debería funcionar correctamente.

Parece que estas usando un framework, de ser así menciona cual es y que versión

@Rodrigo  Por lo que averigue, el error de hidratacion es porque el html generado en el servidor no coincide en el cliente al cargar la pagina. El error arroja que esperaba encontrar un  en un  pero no lo encontro. Más que nada es diferencia entre el html del servidor y el cliente.

@MarcePuente Hola, gracias no note que olvide adjuntarlo. El error que recibo de hidratacion es Expected server HTML to contain a matching <button> in <div>.. Segun es porque el html generado en el servidor no coincide en el cliente al cargar la pagina.

@g.4 Hola, estoy utilizando next.js la version "14.2.3"

En nextJS los componentes se pre-renderizan en el server, luego cuando viene el primer render en el cliente/browser sucede el proceso de Hydration.
Por alguna razón alguno de los componentes relacionados no hace match entre lo que se pre-renderizo en el server y lo que se renderiza en el primer render.
Sospecho que el problema puede estar dentro de ProfileEditForm.
Aunque se puede intentar lo siguiente desde el parent component de Profile para deshabilitar el pre-render en el server del componente Profile:
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
 
const ProfileNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/Profile'), { ssr: false })
 
export default function ParentPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ProfileNoSSR />
    </div>
  )
}

O con el componente ProfileEditForm:
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
         
const ProfileEditFormNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/ProfileEditForm'), { ssr: false })
         
export default function Profile() {
    //codigo...
    return (
        //codigo...
    <div className="py-6 px-3 mt-32 sm:mt-0 mx-auto flex justify-center">
          { user.id === profile._id  
            ? <ProfileEditFormNoSSR profile={profile} onUpdateProfile={handleUpdateProfile} /> 
            : (
               isFollowing 
               ? <Button onClick={() => handleUnfollow() } className='bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-400 text-white normal-case py-2 px-4'>Dejar de seguir</Button>
                : <Button onClick={() => handleFollow(id, user.id)} className='bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-400 text-white normal-case py-2 px-4'>Seguir</Button>
                 )
            }
       </div>
    //codigo
    )
}

Se configura el componente Profile o ProfileEditFormNoSSR para ser cargado como componente dinámico y además que no se pre-renderize en el server ssr:false. Puede que esto funcione.
React Hydration Error en NextJS
